# Using TextField with ForEach in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-foreach

I am trying to display a dynamic list of text fields using a `ForEach`. The following code is working as expected: I can add/remove text fields, and the binding is correct. However, when I move the `items` in a `ObservableObject` view model, it does not work anymore and it crashes with an `index out of bounds` error. Why is that? How can I make it work?

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var items = ["A", "B", "C"]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(items.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                FieldView(value: Binding<String>(get: {
                    items[index]
                }, set: { newValue in
                    items[index] = newValue
                })) {
                    items.remove(at: index)
                }
            }
            Button("Add") {
                items.append("")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct FieldView: View {
    @Binding var value: String
    let onDelete: () -> Void
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            TextField("item", text: $value)
            Button(action: {
                onDelete()
            }, label: {
                Image(systemName: "multiply")
            })
        }
    }
}
```

The view model I am trying to use:

```swift
class ViewModel: Observable {
    @Published var items: [String]
}
```

```swift
@ObservedObject var viewModel: ViewModel
```

I found many questions dealing with the same problem but I could not make one work with my case. Some of them do not mention the `TextField`, some other are not working (anymore?).

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By checking the bounds inside the `Binding`, you can solve the issue:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ViewModel = ViewModel(items: ["A", "B", "C"])
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(viewModel.items.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                FieldView(value: Binding<String>(get: {
                    guard index < viewModel.items.count else { return "" } // <- HERE
                    return viewModel.items[index]
                }, set: { newValue in
                    viewModel.items[index] = newValue
                })) {
                    viewModel.items.remove(at: index)
                }
            }
            Button("Add") {
                viewModel.items.append("")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It is a SwiftUI bug, similar question to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63312802/9607863) for example.

Comment: I am relieved to learn that it is a bug. Hope next version will fix it! It already works when using `List` and `onDelete`.

Answer (score 1):

I can not perfectly explain what is causing that crash, but I've been able to reproduce the error and it looks like after deleting a field,`SwiftUI` is still looking for all `indices` and when it is trying to access the element at a deleted index, it's unable to find it which causes the `index out of bounds` error.

To fix that, we can write a conditional statement to make sure an `element` is searched only if its `index` is included in the collection of `indices`.

```
FieldView(value: Binding<String>(get: {
    if viewModel.items.indices.contains(index) {
        return viewModel.items[index]
    } else {
        return ""
    }
}, set: { newValue in
    viewModel.items[index] = newValue
})) {
    viewModel.items.remove(at: index)
}
```

The above solution solves the problem since it makes sure that the element will not be searched when the number of elements (`items.count`) is not greater than the `index`.

This is just what I've been able to understand, but something else might be happening under the hood.

Comment: This is also a valid answer! Thanks!