# SwiftUI: Perform action on expanding a List row

Tags: swiftui

I have a list of expandable items, which I made following along this post: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-create-expanding-lists

Here is the code:

```swift
struct Examples: View {
    
    private struct Example: Identifiable {
        let id = UUID()
        let string: String
        var items: [Example]?
    }
    
    private let exampleItems: [Example] = [
        Example(string: "One",
                items: [Example(string: "1")]),
        
        Example(string: "Two",
                items: [Example(string: "2")]),
        
        Example(string: "Three",
                items: [Example(string: "3")]),
    ]
    
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(exampleItems, children: \.items) { row in
                Text(row.string)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And I'd like to add a bit of haptic feedback each time a row is expanded or minimised. In **UIKit** you'd just pop this in `tableView(_:didSelectRowAt:)`, and that would be that.

However I can't figure out the **SwiftUI** equivalent, and all my attempts to make things tappable or add buttons etc. break the main action of expanding the list row.

How does one perform an action upon a row being expanded/minimised in SwiftUI?

Comment: `.onTapGesture` works very similar to that method.

Comment: It is better to do that not with default (opaque) hierarchy but having explicit access to DisclosureGroups, like in https://stackoverflow.com/a/63228810/12299030.